# how to convert value of an input tag (type='month') to string like"yyyy-MM"

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

convert value of input (type month) to format "yyyy-MM"

html

```
<input class="bg-success btn btn-dark" type="month" 
    id="timeCheckTimeSheets" ng-model="month">
```

angularjs

```
 $http({
    url: url + $scope.page,
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Authorization: token
    }
  }).then(function(response) {
    $scope.projects = response.data.content;
    var totalPages = response.data.totalPages;
    console.log($scope.month);
  }, function(response) {
    alert('fail')
  })
```

[image]

Comment: instead of giving month, you can define a type near ng-model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for.

```js
const date = new Date();
const year = date.getFullYear();
const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
const formattedDate = year + '-' + month.toString().padStart(2, 0);
console.log(formattedDate);
```

Comment: Thanks again. Because it help me again